# how to navigate to a url from our local host?

Tags: html

I have a url `eg: xyz.net/645636`. I'm trying to access it but it is giving me an error saying cannot get to `xyz.net/645636`. But, I didn't have any problem navigating to that page directly. 
The local host url is `http://localhost:3000/index.html`. 
I'm running my application using node server setup on my local system.

```
<a href="xyz.net/645636"> Example Link </a>
```

The link doesn't have any protocols. Could some one point out where am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Links _always_ have a protocol. If none is specified in a browser's URL bar, it just usually defaults to HTTP. Anything lacking a protocol will be treated as a URL relative to the current page.

Comment: @Siguza The link which I'm using doesn't have a protocol associated with it. When I was taken to that page after typing manually, I don't see any protocol at the beginning of the url.

Comment: Copy that URL and paste it into a text editor - you'll see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It needs a protocol:

```
<a href="http://example.com/645636"> Example Link </a>
```

When you type the address into your browser without one, it adds it for you for convenience.

Comment: when I type in the address, it did not add any thing like http. It was just the same `example.com/645636` in the address bar.

Comment: When I added "http" it took me to the page. But I need to add this "http" to thousands of such urls.

Comment: It does add it, it may not show it. And yes, maybe, but that is what is required.